# How to define a mouse gesture in C#

Tags: c#, mouse, detection, shortcut, registerhotkey

I want to define a mouse gesture in C# with below properties:

1. Firing the event before other applications that have same gesture
2. Define different gesture based on different user mouse speed.

So what is the best solution?

Comment: Check this, it allows you to define mousegestures http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8626/C-Application-to-Create-and-Recognize-Mouse-Gestur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mouse Gestures from CodePlex](https://mousegestures.codeplex.com/) the source code is available if you need to extend the functionality.

Just make sure to read the license before publishing or anything like that.